# Create SwipeListView in Windows 10 UWP apps like in outlook mail app

Tags: listview, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10, swipe

I am creating windows 10 UWP app. I need to show options for list view item on swiping left/right on it. It should be [like this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=outlook%20mail%20app&es_sm=119&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAmoVChMI9NyV3crVxwIVCQaOCh3Ongif&biw=1440&bih=828#tbm=isch&q=outlook%20mail%20app%20swipe&imgrc=f75e5ZcNI0mUHM%3A). If it is available in Windows 10 outlook mail app, why didn't they provide tutorial for creating it. 
Help me with this. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Would be nice to accept the answer of comment on why it's still not a solution for your problem...

Answer (score 8):

Dave Smits has created a control for this and detailed how to use it on his blog http://www.familie-smits.com/development-tips/tinder-control-for-your-windows-app

The source is up on github! Do note that this was still for WinRT wp8 and not for UWP, but I would assume it should be portable / workable in UWP too.

If not ping him on twitter @davesmits

** Update 2015/09/14
There is a Windows 10 UWP one available on github here https://github.com/FrayxRulez/SwipeListView

Comment: Do you think it is possible to implement both swipe and reorder functionality on the same ListView and to trigger those two events with finger ? On Win10 outlook it seems drag & drop is only possible by using the mouse

Comment: I haven't completely digged through the control's code, but pretty sure it's possible. For reordering items, check this reply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34497344/drag-and-drop-item-in-same-listview/34497837#34497837

Comment: @Bart thanks i forgot to specify the allowDrop attribute! great

Comment: my 2 cents on the question. Super easy to convert to UWP. The only thing to be aware of is that `PhoneTouchTargetOverhang` doesn't exist, so I just replaced by 12. Works great!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this nuget package its better with multiple options
https://github.com/brookshi/LLMListView

```
  Swipe Left/Right with one action
  Swipe Left/Right with one action with animation
  Swipe Right with fixed and multiple actions
```

**some extras**

```
  Pull to refresh
  Pull with a button
  Load More 
  Load More in Group view
```

here is a screenshot https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brookshi/LLMListView/master/list%20view.gif