# Drag and drop item in same ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, drag-and-drop, uwp

I have following `ListView`

```
<ListView Name="listAccounts" Width="300" AllowDrop="True" SelectionMode="Single" CanDragItems="True" CanDrag="True" CanReorderItems="True" Background="{ThemeResource myBackground}" DragItemsStarting="listAccounts_DragItemsStarting" Drop="listAccounts_Drop">
```

and defined my event handlers as

```
private void listAccounts_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Data.SetData("itemIndex", (e.Items[0] as AccountList).Text.ToString());
}

private async void listAccounts_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string itemIndexString = await e.Data.GetView().GetTextAsync("itemIndex");
}
```

I don't know what else I can do. I want to realize the movement of the list items in the same list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went over to the official Windows 10 samples, looked for the [drag-drop sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop) and trimmed it down (like removing the drag from target to source). Turns out you don't even have to handle any events to make re-ordering in a single `ListView` work.

```
<ListView x:Name="TargetListView"
                Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="8,4"
                CanReorderItems="True" CanDrag="True" AllowDrop="True"
                />
```

Check your `ObservableCollection` after reordering items and you'll notice it's correct. If you want to track the re-ordering, you'll have to check the `CollectionChanged` event on your `ObservableCollection`, as there is no event on the `ListView` to do this.

If you want to support drag & drop accross multilple listviews, I'd say have another look at the sample.